# Suppress MongoDB unique errors on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am running a bulk insert with `continueOnError` on, so that I can insert an array of documents to a collection with a unique constraint; adding documents that pass, ignoring the ones that fail.

However, despite the `continueOnError` flag on, Mongo still returns the error; this makes the framework I use think that there's a problem. I would know how to suppress all errors, but this bulk insert is only one of many operations, and I'd still need to see errors from those (mind you, I'd want to see errors of any other kind than 11000 from this bulk insert too).

I am using the official MongoDB driver under Node.js; and I'm controlling the flow with [ff](https://github.com/gameclosure/ff).

How do I suppress the unique failures for the bulk insert, without suppressing other errors, or disrupting the flow?

```
var mongo_options = {
    collection: { strict: true },
    insert: { w: 1, strict: true },
    insertbulk: { w: 1, strict: true, continueOnError: true, keepGoing: true }
}

var f = ff(this, function () {
    this.connection.collection(table, mongo_options.collection, f.slot());  
}, function (collection) {
    // DON'T SUPPRESS THIS
    collection.insert(data, mongo_options.insert, f.slot());
}, function () {
    this.connection.collection("tags", mongo_options.collection, f.slot()); 
}, function (collection) {
    // SUPPRESS THIS
    collection.insert(tag_array, mongo_options.insertbulk, f.slot());
}).cb(next); // <-- error going out into the world
```

Comment: Are you inserting into a `mongod` or a `mongos`?  Also, what version of MongoDB and the Node.js driver are you using?

Comment: I am also getting similar issue. Did you found any solution to this?